# retrieving individual values from serialise function in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to update my database using AJAX.
I have a form which contains text fields. 
I POST those values using serialize function in j query. 
Got output:
`Firstname=Sometext1&Lastname=Sometext2&Phone=12345`

Then i used the split() function so the result is

```
Firstname=Sometext1,Lastname=Sometext2,Phone=12345
```

Now how do I use these values to insert into my database. 
How can I get individual values i.e. Sometext1,Sometext2,12345 in different variables

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: why you are serializing, pass them as a json object to method, if using post. Place the content in request body.

Comment: how about a second split?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easiest way would be to use a second split and loop through the output:

```
var input = "Firstname=Sometext1&Lastname=Sometext2&Phone=12345";
var split = input.split("&"); //["Firstname=Sometext1","Lastname=Sometext2","Phone=12345"]

var output = [];

//loop through split
for(var i=0;i<split.length;i++){
    var subSplit= split[i].split("="); //split up each value again
    output.push(subSplit[1]); //subSplit[0] would be the key, subSplit[1] the value
}

console.log(output); //output: ["Sometext1","Sometext2","12345"]
```

...would be easier to give better advice if we knew more of your code, tough...especially the reason why the data is serialized that way would be interesting...